# html source code from Arduino

Tags: html, if-statement, arduino

I am making a home appliance control device using arduino. I got this html code from the website. What is the code to get the value from the Arduino?
I think

```
$("#temperatureDisplay").load('temperature_display.php');
```

This part would be a receiving the value from the Arduino, but I am confusing. If I know what is code for receiving the value, how can I use if statement to change the background color with different value of output from Arduino?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Weather Station</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="data">
    <div class="dataTitle">Temperature: </div>
    <div id="temperatureDisplay">Waiting for data ...</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    setInterval(function() 
{
    $("#temperatureDisplay").load('temperature_display.php');
}, 1000);

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

This is php file and the data file is just number. This number is always changed with the Arduino.

```
<?php

$myFile = "temp_data.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$line = fgets($fh);
fclose($fh);

echo $line;

?>
```

Comment: That jQuery statement is loading the result of the php file into that DOM element. That appears to be the only part of this page that is talking with the arduino.

Comment: This html file call the php file and php file call the text file. And one thing I wonder is how can I make a variable for this text file for if statement?

Comment: Can you add the php file to your question? I am not sure what value it is returning

Comment: I did, I am trying to assign output value to a variable for my if statement. But, I cannot find any solution for that.

Comment: Where is the `if` ? How to you generate `temp_data.txt`  ?

Comment: That is a what I want to ask. How can I generate temp_data.txt in javascript? and how can I use if statement in the script using the variable of temp_data.txt?